# How to store tags to custom entity?

Tags: tags, sulu

I have custom entity and tag field defined as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sulu\Bundle\TagBundle\Tag\TagInterface")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="venue_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="venue_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idTags", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $tags;
```

Then I have setter (adder actually) like this:

```
public function addTag(TagInterface $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;

    return $this;
}
```

Field is added to form details XML like:

```
    <property name="tags" type="tag_selection">
        <meta>
            <title lang="de">Tags</title>
            <title lang="en">Tags</title>
        </meta>

        <tag name="sulu.search.field" type="tags"/>
    </property>
```

And inside my admin controller class I have mapping method:

```
    protected function mapDataToEntity(array $data, Venue $entity): void
    {  
        ....
        foreach ($data['tags'] as $tag) {
           $entity->addTag($tag);
        }
        ....
```

However as `$data['tags']` I receive here array of string and my `addTag()` requires instance of `TagInterface` object. How can I create that object from string I have and generally is this the proper way for storing tags.

**Update:**

As @Johannes suggested added field:

```
/**
 * @var TagManagerInterface
 */
private $tagManager;
```

and to constructor like:

```
public function __construct(
    ViewHandlerInterface $viewHandler,
    ...
    TagManagerInterface $tagManager
) {
    $this->viewHandler = $viewHandler;
    ...
    $this->tagManager = $tagManager;
    parent::__construct($viewHandler);
}
```

And then trying to add tags like this:

```
    $tagEntities = $this->tagManager->resolveTagNames($data['tags']);
    foreach ($tagEntities as $tagEntity) {
       $entity->addTag($tagEntity);
    }
```

But then I get error:

***Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Venue::addTag() must implement interface Sulu\Bundle\TagBundle\Tag\TagInterface, int given, called in /var/www/html/src/Controller/Admin/VenueController.php on line 147***

What I'm doing wrong? Like I'm getting tag ids? Should I load tags somehow?

**Update 2:**

After adding `findById()` saving tags works. However, now I found 2 more problems:

1. Even relations are saved well in database just after saving tags are not displayed any more in tags field. Also if I go to overview page and get back to edit entity selected (saved) tags are not re-populated. What else I have to add so saved tags in database would be used actually?
2. If I fist select "Tag1" and click "Save" it's saved well. But if I edit entity again and select "Tag1" again Sulu tries to create new row with same keys and I get error message: "***SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-1' for key 'venue_tags.PRIMARY'***". I guess previously saved keys should be deleted first but how and where would be the optimal way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the TagManager service (id: `sulu_tag.tag_manager` or `Sulu\Bundle\TagBundle\Tag\TagManagerInterface`):

```php
$tagIds = $tagManager->resolveTagNames($data['tags']);
foreach ($tagIds as $tagId) {
   $entity->addTag($tagManager->findById($tagId));
}
```

Comment: Almost there. I updated my question, please check the update.

Comment: Thank you Johannes, that works. However I faced 2 more problems. I would really appreciate if you could check on my second question update.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I added to my entity new method:

```
public function removeAllTags()
{
    foreach ($this->getTags() as $tag) {
        $this->removeTag($tag);
    }
}
```

which I'm calling from mapDataToEntity() before adding new tags:

```
    $tagEntities = $this->tagManager->resolveTagNames($data['tags']);
    $entity->removeAllTags();
    foreach ($tagEntities as $tagEntity) {
       $entity->addTag($this->tagManager->findById($tagEntity));
    }
```

And this solves doubled keys but also solves tag removal potential issue.

Comment: As long as the variable `$tags` is from type `Collection` you can use `$this->tags->clear()` inside of the `removeAllTags` function

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your class that should fix your first issue

```php
/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("tags")
 */
public function getTagNameArray()
{
    $tags = [];
    foreach ($this->getTags() as $tag) {
        $tags[] = $tag->getName();
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

To fix the second one you have to make the addTag method aware that you cannot have multiple relations to the same tag (check if the tag is already in the collection there).

Comment: Sorry, but adding getTagNameArray() didn't help. I actually already had that method, but annotations were missing. Now it's just like in you example, but reloading is still not working.

Ok about addTag() method.

Comment: Solved. Problem was that I'm storing tags in new relationship table and some  function was making query by names, not by id. Relation setup was a bit different than in example code. Thank for help anyway.